# Why does singular value decomposition simultaneously diagonalize a symmetric matrix and its square?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, svd, principal-component-analysis

So I took an online course on machine learning and in this course the instructor said that the eigenvectors of a covariance matrix (for principal components analysis) can be computed by a singular value decomposition.

Say the covariance matrix is $A$. The SVD yields $A = U \Sigma V^t$ and with $A^t A = A^2$ both $V$ and $U$ diagonalize $A^2$, i.e. $V^t A^2 V = U^t A^2 U = \Sigma^2$. What I do not understand is why U and V also diagonalize A directly, i.e. $V^t A V = U^t A U = \Sigma$.

Diagonalizable matrices that commute can be simultaneously diagonalized and so I understand that $A^2$ and $A$ can be simultaneously diagonalized. However, the dimension of each eigenspace can generally be $>1$ which means that a set of eigenvectors that diagonalizes $A^2$ does not have to diagonalize $A$ as well. So why does the SVD algorithm automatically find the eigenvectors of $A^2$ that are simultaneously eigenvectors $A$?

I am not a mathematician, please have mercy if the answer is kind of obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covariance matrices are positive-semidefinite, and PSD matrices have unique PSD square roots (given by taking the unique nonnegative square root of each eigenvalue). This means that $V^T A V$ is the unique PSD square root of $V^T A^2 V$. We have $V^T A^2 V = \Sigma^2$ and the unique PSD square root of $\Sigma^2$ is $\Sigma$, so $V^T A V = \Sigma$.

We can give an alternative analysis in terms of eigenspaces as follows. Consider some eigenspace $E_{\lambda}$ of $A^2$. By definition we have $A^2 v = \lambda v$ for all $v \in E_{\lambda}$. Since $A$ commutes with $A^2$, it restricts to a map $A : E_{\lambda} \to E_{\lambda}$ which squares to $\lambda$. You are correct that in general it does not follow that $A$ acts by a scalar (and good job spotting this possibility!), but if $\lambda \ge 0$ and $A$ is PSD then $A$ must act by $\sqrt{\lambda}$. This is because $\sqrt{\lambda}$ is the only possible eigenvalue of $A$ here (and $A$ is diagonalizable by the spectral theorem).

Comment: Thank you very much!

I didn't know that a positive-semidefinite matrix has a unique positive-semidefinite square root. The proof I've read (https://yutsumura.com/a-positive-definite-matrix-has-a-unique-positive-definite-square-root/) showed how to construct a PSD square root and then that there can be no other PSD square root. That makes me wonder, however, if the square root is still unique without the restriction on PSD matrices?

Comment: @chris: nope. You can take square roots of the eigenvalues with either sign in general. For example the identity matrix has square roots $\text{diag}(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ (and other square roots as well, e.g. any conjugate of these).